# SQL Day-over-Day count miscalculation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm encountering a bug in my SQL code that calculates the day-over-day (DoD) count difference. This table (curr_day) summarizes the count of trades on any business day (i.e. excluding weekends and government-mandated holidays) and is joined by a similar table (prev_day) that is day-lagged (previous day). The joining is based on the day's rank; for example the first day on the curr_day table is Jan-01 and it's rank is 1, the first day (rank 1) for the prev_day table is Dec-31.

My issue is that the trade count does not seem to calculate positive changes (see table below), only negative or no changes. This problem does not affect other fields that calculate the value of a trade, simply the amount of trades on a given day.

Sample of query

```
with curr_day as (select GROUP, COUNT from DB where DATE is not HOLIDAY),

prev_day as (select rank()over(partition by GROUP order by DATE) as RANK, GROUP, DATE, COUNT
from curr_day where DATE is not HOLIDAY)

select ID, DATE, curr_day.COUNT-prev_day.COUNT
from (select rank()over(partition by curr_day.GROUP order by curr_day.DATE) as RANK
      from curr_day
      where curr_day.DATE >= (select min(curr_day.DATE)+1) from curr_day)
left join prev_day on curr_day.RANK = prev_day.RANK and curr_day.GROUP = prev_day.GROUP)
;
```

Output table

```
Date       | Group | Count | DoD_Cnt_Diff
2020-12-31 |   A   |   1   |   0
2021-01-01 |   A   |   1   |   0
2021-01-02 |   A   |   0   |  -1
2021-01-03 |   A   |   1   | (null)
2021-01-04 |   A   |   0   |  -1
2021-01-05 |   A   |   0   |   0
2021-12-31 |   B   |   0   |   0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve], maybe with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18) if you need a lot of data to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: This looks like MySQL, not Oracle database. Please check your tags.

Comment: It's definitely Oracle SQL Developer